# How to include my application pdb files path within symbols path

Tags: .net, windbg, unmanaged, symbols

I am analysing my application memory dump file in windbg. My symbol path is currently setup as follows.

SRV*G:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

My application has managed and unmanaged components. Probelm is right now for my unmanaged calls, I am not getting function names. How can I include path for my own application symbols so that I start getting function names also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first set the symbol path to your own PDBs

```
.sympath G:\MyPDBs
```

and then add the Microsoft server

```
.symfix+ G:\Symbols
```

so in the end your overall expanded symbol path looks like this:

```
G:\MyPDBs;SRV*G:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Don't just copy your PDBs flat into G:\Symbols. WinDbg won't find them in a structured symbol store.